# Using Windows sftp to server - how to append data to an existing file

Tags: sftp

I am on a windows workstation and have a file that I want to upload to a server and append to the end of an existing file. I use sftp as the transfer tool.

I've looked at the man page and not found any solution.

My workaround, for now, is to sftp the file to the host and then ssh to the host to do the append.

I'm sure there must be something I'm missing.

Comment: You can do `cat localfile | ssh user@host "cat >> existingfile"`. Replace `cat` with `type` if you're using cmd.exe. This won't work if the host prompts you for a password.

Comment: thank you - worked great - it's an interesting workaround.

Comment: To answer your literal question: The OpenSSH `sftp` client does not support appending. So a workaround or use another SFTP client is necessary.